# How to change toolbar limiter dropdown to links

Tags: magento2, toolbar

How i can change the product toolbar limiter dropdown to links,

like: 9 | 15 | 30 | All

Comment: When I click on the link it only adds '?product_list_limit=' not the limit in URL.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/153392)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by replacing the following code in Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml

```
<select id="limiter" data-role="limiter" class="limiter-options">
            <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
                </option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
 </select>
```

with

```
<?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
        <a data-role="limiter" href="#" data-value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
            class="selected"<?php endif ?>>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
        </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```